# built in encode and decode unsafe with databind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to implement some client side encoding/decoding onto a databind text box where data is passed between the tb and db.

What I have tried so far is server side functions with visual basic, however when the code is sent through I get an encoding error before the code's had a chance to run so it appears to me that JQuery/JS is the way to go to achieve this.

Can someone explain why it's unsafe to use htmlEncode and Decode like the below and how I need to go about stripping out the html using client side workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

```
function htmlEncode(value) {
return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value) {
    return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem of this approach is that it does not encode quotes, so if the input is used for an attribute value for example, it may break the html.

```
elem.innerHTML = '<div title="' + htmlEncode('" onhover="alert(1)') + '">X</div>';
```

will happily set the element to `<div title="" onhover="alert(1)">X</div>` and it can run the user's script then.